# LAMP multiple websites

Tags: php, ubuntu, web, lamp

I'm newbie to Ubuntu. Installed LAMP. Have several questions about it

1) let's say first websites dir looks like : var/www/first/ and second ones: var/www/second. How can i set up multiple website, and use them with seperate ports (like http://localhost:81/ and http://localhost:82/ ) as on IIS?

2) How can i change default location of webserver (default is var/www) or exact website?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Create [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html) in your apache configuration.  On my install of Ubuntu (which is older), the configuration file is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.

2) In the configuration file mentioned in 1, you can change the DocumentRoot of the default site.

Answer (score 1):

1) In your Apache `httpd.conf` configure a new virtualhost.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

2)  In your Apache `httpd.conf` change the DocumentRoot to your "new" folder.